# How to estimate parameter in simulation?

Tags: r, estimation, simulation

I am fairly new to R and is exploring simulation to estimate the parameter n:

1) Z is a vector of n draws from N(0,1)

2) Probability of max(Z)>4 equals 0.25

What is the best way in R to estimate the parameter n to satisfy these two conditions? I got stuck trying to avoid looping or exhaustive search in the code. Thanks!

Comment: - Is this homework? 
-What have you tried? 
-You did not try googling "distribution of the maximum of normal random variables"
- This is unrelated to Quant Finance!
Anyway have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

You don't really need to carry out a simulation to find this quantity.

Find the CDF of $\max(Z)$

$$Pr(\max(Z)>4)=1-Pr(Z_1 \le 4, \ldots, Z_n \le 4)$$

then use the independence of $Z_i$ to get an expression in terms of CDF of $N(0,1)$.